# Firestore timestamp format in a text populated ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, timestamp

`ListView` populated from snapshot values, values are inside a Text.

The data is a timestamp in Firestore looking like this:

[image]

Currently they are generated like:

[image]

Added toDate()

```
Text(
      'Date: ${snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('usoOn').toDate()}',
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                        ),
```

and used to look like this:

[image]

Had to remove toDate() because of an error NoSuchMethodError timestamp has no instance method to date. Similar to the one below.

Trying to change the format to look like this, it works with errores, both in the console and if you scroll below the ListView you get a big red message.

[image]

Most of the answers around that I found are related to using a String or a single value, not a populated ListView taking data from a snapshot.

Thank you for any help with this, still green on Flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to use FirestoreListView, it has better way to change the data type.
Also some of the errors related to class int are because some of the data was wrong. Some was manually added during testing and had numerical instead of timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this extension, add it some global scope (outside your class) :

```
extension DateTimeExt on DateTime {
  String yourFormat() {
    final date = this;
    final hour = date.hour.toString().padLeft(2, "0");
    final minute = date.minute.toString().padLeft(2, "0");;
    final day = date.day.toString().padLeft(2, "0");;
    final month = date.month.toString().padLeft(2, "0");;
    final year = date.year.toString().substring(2);
    return "$hour:$minute - $day-$month-$year";
  }
}
```

and use it like this example:

```
  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  print(date.yourFormat()); // 03:05 - 30-11-2022
```

in your example you can use it like this:

```
Text(
      'Date: ${snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('usoOn').toDate().yourFormat()}',
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly I had to remove the toDate(). because in the end of the listview I was getting an error.
https://i.imgur.com/ygQVt3g_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand

Comment: if you're talking about timestamp use this to make date from it new var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp * 1000);